Is alcohol usage declining among younger demographics in the US?
Gallup makes the following claim:

Young adults in the U.S. have become progressively less likely to use alcohol over the past two decades, with the percentages of 18- to 34-year-olds saying they ever drink, that they drank in the past week and that they sometimes drink more than they should all lower today.

Is this true?
It's hard for me to imagine a world where college students are drinking less (or where high school-educated 21 year olds are drinking less).
How is this measured?(For example, are alcohol-related ER visits declining for college students and/or people aged 18-35?)

Could you source that and directly quote the claim for us?

This site is for skepticism about notable claims, so your question needs to include a notable quotation from someone that claims that alcohol usage is declining. Otherwise it could get questions like "Is it true that pine trees communicate by using squirrels to pass messages?". That question wouldn't be allowed unless it could demonstrate that some famous person or publication has already made that claim.

One of the reasons we want a cite is to find out where they are talking about. The answer might be different in different regions.

I have re-opened with @pinegulf's edit to add a notability link, but the Gallup article includes information about why they make this claim, so be sure your answers have references at least as reliable as a Gallup poll.

I, personally, would love to see an analysis of cannabis use in the same demographic. My eyebrows raised when I saw the Gallup article didn't mention it. Has cannabis "replaced" alcohol?

"It's hard for me to imagine a world where college students are drinking less" - Presumably, this is because you imagine a world where college students drink a ton? In that case, you shouldn't be surprised if college students are drinking less, you should probably be more surprised if they are drinking more, if you already think of them as high-drinking. I think you have your logic backwards here, the claim isn't that they're drinking less now than some other category, the claim is that they're drinking less than college students used to.

@Oddthinking: Here is some data: https://www.samhsa.gov/data/all-reports?f%5B0%5D=population_groups%3A284&f%5B1%5D=report_type%3A367&f%5B2%5D=survey_type%3A377&items_per_page=50, gathering the data to properly answer this question requires too much manual clicking through the tables. That data is there though if someone has more patience.

Interesting. I found "Surveys have documented a decline in alcohol consumption among all age groups… including young adults", but that's so old (1996) the "young adults" surveyed probably wouldn't all object to being called "older adults" now.

I'm not sure what an answer to the edited question would be. "gallup is generally reputable so probably this is true?" Another pollster? RE: ER visits, this is canada, but shows a general increase https://www.cmaj.ca/content/191/29/E804

(I guess both "ER visits" and "pollster responses" are potentially imperfect proxies; ER visits would increase if there was increasing awareness of the dangers of being so drunk you aspirate vomit. (I was taught that if I'm considering putting somebody in a recovery position I need to call EMS; my dad remembers putting friends to bed blacked out and letting them sleep it off.) and pollsters would be skewed by stigma etc

Along with the non-drinking population increasing, as opposed to a reduction in the habit?
